# $\int \frac{\left(x+1\right)}{x\left(1+xe^x\right)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus

I know I asked this earlier today however I've deleted that and this question is about a different approach to the same problem
$$\int  \frac{\left(x+1\right)}{x\left(1+xe^x\right)^2}dx$$

My attempt:-
let $ln(x)=y$

so the integral simplifies to

$$\int \frac{e^y+1}{(1+e^{y+e^y})^2}$$

so let $e^y+y=t$

so we have $\int \frac{dt}{(1+e^t)^2}$

two questions is my approach correct until here, and what do I do from here

Comment: You could do substitution $z = e^{t}$, then apply partial fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the substitution $t=xe^x \ \ \ \ dt=e^x(x+1)dx$

$$
\int \frac{e^x(x+1)}{xe^x(xe^x+1)^2}dx=\int \frac{dt}{t(t+1)^2}=\int (\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{1}{\left(t+1\right)^{2}})dt=\ln\left|\frac{xe^{x}}{xe^{x}+1}\right|+\frac{1}{e^{x}x+1}+C
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{dt}{(1+e^t)^2}$

$1+e^t = u, du = e^t dt, du/(u-1)= dt$

$\int \frac{du}{u^2(u-1)}$

$-\int \frac{du}{u} - \int \frac{du}{u^2} + \int \frac{du}{u-1}$

Proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First of all multiply the numerator and denominator by $e^{x}$. Therefore the above integral will become

$$\int \frac{e^{x}(x+1)}{xe^{x}(1+xe^{x})^{2}}dx$$. Now you substitute $(1+xe^{x})=u$. Therefore, $e^{x}(x+1)dx=du$. Therefore finally the integral will become

$$\int \frac{1}{(u-1)u^{2}}du$$. Now write $1=u-(u-1)$. Therefore finally this integral will be $$\int \frac{1}{u(u-1)}du-\int \frac{1}{u^{2}}du$$. Now I think you can easily integrate $$\int \frac{1}{u(u-1)}du$$. So, try to solve this with my hints.

Regards

DEB SANKAR ROY